# How to forward declare CoreFoundation types?

Tags: ios, objective-c, forward-declaration, core-foundation

It's easy to forward declare Objective C classes.

```
@class ClassWhoseHeaderNotYetImported;
```

However, this strategy doesn't work with CoreFoundation types like `CVImageBufferRef` or anything that inherits from `CFTypeRef`. What's the right way to forward declare CoreFoundation types in objective C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@class` doesn't work for Core Foundation types because they're not classes, they're structs, e.g. if you look at the definition of `CVImageBufferRef` you see this:

```
typedef struct __CVBuffer *CVBufferRef;
...
typedef CVBufferRef CVImageBufferRef;
```

So in order to forward-declare a CF type, you need to know what the underlying struct is. You can look it up in Xcode fairly easily with ⌘-click.  If there are multiple levels, as here, you don't need to declare all of them (unless you need to use the intermediates). The following should work

```
typedef struct __CVBuffer *CVImageBufferRef;
```

If you really can't be bothered to look up the types, you could probably get away with `void *`. It's technically not safe, but it will never fail on iOS or OSX unless Apple seriously f-s stuff up.